# iOS: presentViewController in different storyboard is not showing navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistoryboard

I'm loading view controller in different storyboard:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NewStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
NewViewController *detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];
[self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

[image]
But is not showing the navigation bar in the device. Any of you knows why this is happening or how can I fix this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: In your picture, `NewViewController` is a plain `UIViewController`. If you load that via code, you are ***not*** loading a UINavigationController, so when you `presentViewController` it is not pushing it onto a navigation stack... Are you calling this code from a view controller that is already *in* a NavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NewStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
NewViewController *detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than instantiating a ViewController from an identifier, try using performsegueWithIdentifier to transition. When you instantiate the ViewController, it is created independent of the Navigation Controller that it comes from.

1. Open your Storyboard and click on the segue (the arrow between view controllers), and assign an identifier to it, i.e. "SegueToNewViewController".
2. Call the following method from a ViewController that is a child of a navigation controller:

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueToNewViewController" sender:self];

This will perform a segue from the calling ViewController to the new ViewController, including the NavigationBar